# Automatically restoring verticality of the edges of a scanned photo

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-manipulation, scanner, gimp

I want to scan a collection of rectangular photos, both color and black-and-white.
I am generally quite happy with the scanning, but I run into some
practical problems, due to the fact that photos are placed by hand and may not be well
aligned with the scanning canvas (or the edges of the scanner)

I assume that my photo has been scanned into a white background
rectangle containing the rectangular picture I want, possibly not
aligned with the edge of the white rectangle.

Is there an application (preferably running on Linux) that can rotate
automatically the scan so that the picture edges are
horizontal/vertical? If it also crop out the surrounding white
background, it is even better (though proper Unix design would separate this issue).

I know how to do that by hand with Gimp, checking the rotation with my
eyes. But I would like to have it done automatically.

To make things clearer with actual images: given the first image below with the irregular white border, I would like to automatically extract the second one, without any surrounding white.

[image]
              
[image]

Note: I had to add the dashed-line to show the edges of the first image.
If you want to test a proposed solution for the automatic extraction, you should rather
[**use this image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs5FM.jpg).

Comment: http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14972 ???

Comment: If your images have text, have a look at [deskew](https://pypi.org/project/deskew/). It works pretty well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/). This is typically installed by default with a lot of the more popular distros. If not you can use your distros package manager to install it.

#### Normal image rotation

```
$ sudo yum install ImageMagick

-or-

$ sudo apt-get install ImageMagick
```

ImageMagick includes many CLI tools, one of which is `convert`. Using `convert` you can rotate images like so:

```
$ convert -rotate "90" in.jpg out.jpg
```

There are many more examples on using `convert` [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). The rest of the tools included with ImageMagick can do image editing, scaling, and annotating.

#### Deskewing

The other method for rotating images that are typically off a bit vertically or horizontally is called deskewing.

From the [ImageMagick online command line options help](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#deskew):

```
-deskew threshold{%}
straighten an image. A threshold of 40% works for most images.

Use -set option:deskew:auto-crop true | false to auto crop the image.
```

To use this option, you'd use the `convert` CLI tool that's another of ImageMagicks CLI tools:

```
 $ convert skewed.jpeg -deskew 40% not_skewed.jpg
```

#### References

- [List of ImageMagick CLI tools](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php)
- [How to deskew a scanned text-page with ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546181/how-to-deskew-a-scanned-text-page-with-imagemagick)

Comment: Ah. You want to deskew the image see here https://stackoverflow.com/q/41546181/33204

Comment: Thanks again. That seems to be it. I did not know the technical word. Still, I am a bit surprised since skewing normally denotes some kind of distortion, while in this case there is no distortion, only a rotation. Can I be sure it will only rotate my image, witout distorting it?  Another point is that this option is not listed on the imagemagick page imagemagick.org/script/convert.php , though it is available on my Linux. Actually, I have some difficulty finding on the web a description or definition of deskew and what it does precisely. I am still looking ... nay suggestion?

Comment: @babou - I believe it's lossless, it looks like it's setting the deskew attribute in the image header itself - http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29229.

Comment: Is there really a standard deskew attribute, that would contain both
the angle of rotation and the center of rotation? But this corresponds
to an image that is not aligned with the canvas, i.e. with edges that
are not horizontal or vertical. This is odd. Strange also that I cannot find an official definition of deskew in imagemagick, but only forum discussions.

Comment: @babou - I agree on both points. Haven't seen a definition, I'd have to look into the ImageMagick source to confirm the equation used to do it beyond the forum post.

Answer (score 3):

I recently needed to digitalize the set of more than 500 photos made by film cameras. And needed to auto-trim and auto-rotate all of them.

Those parameters that worked better for me:

```
convert myFile.jpg -fuzz 30% -trim +repage -deskew 40% cropped_file.jpg
```

And here if you want to apply it to the entire folder:

```
mkdir cropped
for i in `ls *.JPG`; do convert $i -fuzz 30% -trim +repage -deskew 40% cropped/`basename $i JPG`jpg; done
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading [this blog post](https://www.opensourceforu.com/2015/03/automate-the-cropping-of-photos-from-scanned-album-pages/), I found [this bash script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php) which uses [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) : download it, `chmod +x` it and then I managed to rotate & crop my scanned photos with the following command:

```
multicrop -c 50,50 -f 40 -d 50 scanned_photo_in.jpg extracted_photo_out.jpg
```

- `-c 50,50` is to detect the background color from pixel at 50,50 (default is 0,0)
- `-f 40` is the "fuzz value for separating background color expressed as percent" (default is 10)
- `-d 50` will discard any region that has a width or height smaller than this size (default is to not discard anything)

Here is a bash script to run this command for any jpg files in the current folder and put the extracted photos in `extracted` sub folder:

```bsh
mkdir extracted; for PHOTO in *.jpg; do multicrop -c 50,50 -f 40 -d 50 $PHOTO extracted/$PHOTO; done
```